# Android - Picasso 2.5.2 - display watermark

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, picasso

I've been trying to display a watermark on the images loaded with Picasso. I found this: [Picasso - transformation bitmap quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416004/picasso-transformation-bitmap-quality) , which is interesting to load the overlaid image using the .transform property, but I cannot find the BitmapTransformations.OverlayTransformation library anywhere.
For context sake, I'm loading a GridView and populating it with Picasso, like this:
MainActivity:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

On ImageAdapter:

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(mContext);
     picasso.load(foto.getURL())
    .placeholder(R.raw.place_holder)
    .error(R.raw.big_problem)
    .resize(150, 150)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView);
```

On layout XML:
the GridView is within a RelativeLayout

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks

ps: this is how it's used on the link:

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(item.getPicture())
        .transform(new BitmapTransformations.OverlayTransformation(
            context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_play_video))
        .error(R.drawable.picture_placeholder)
        .into(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for adding watermark text to your images with a picasso transformation:

https://gist.github.com/odedhb/4c72b1d73ddd7ece1949